# Suitable instance counting CNN for training on polygonal masks

Tags: cnn, semantic-segmentation

I have a medical dataset labeled with polygonal masks (rather than rectangle boxes). It works well for pixel annotation with UNet to generate masks of healthy vs damaged skin. Now I need to do instance counting. Most of the CNNs like YOLOv4 consumes bounding boxes, not polygons.

Which CNN should I use for instance counting given that my dataset consists of labeled polygons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which CNN should I use for instance counting given that my dataset consists of labeled polygons?

CNNs for instance segmentation. To start with you can try Mask-RCNN. [Here](https://paperswithcode.com/sota/instance-segmentation-on-coco) are all state of the art CNNs for instance segmentation. You will also find code for most of them.